# async whilst seems to be use more and more stack even with setImmediate

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the next example, I tried to prevent filling the stack. That is why I used setImmediate... It is supposed to work. However, when I watched the stack trace, it seems to get longer and longer, implying the setImmediate does not work.
Is there anything wrong? What do you think?

```
var longjohn = require('longjohn');             
var async = require('async');
var i = 0
var test = function() { return true; }
var iter = function(c) {
   console.log(i++);
   console.trace();
   setImmediate(c);
}
noop = function() {}
async.whilst(test, iter, noop);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Async source code?  Or perhaps reached out to the author, Caolan McMahon (http://caolanmcmahon.com/)?

Comment: reached out to the author, no reply